# Trying to build a Table but keep getting an array with index values

Tags: lua

So I'm trying to build something like so (table t0)

```
{
  l1 = {
    ['t1'] = function(params) print('t1) end,
    ['t2'] = function(params) print('t2') end
  },
  l2 = {
    ['t3'] = function(params) print('t3') end
  }
}
```

But every find I try to do something like

```
t0.l1[#t0.l1+1] = { ['t1'] = function(params) print('t1) end }
```

It ends up becoming an array with an index value:

```
l1   table: 0x...
1    table: 0x... ({ ['t1'] = function(params) print('t1) end })
2    table: 0x... ({ ['t2'] = function(params) print('t1) end })
```

How to I insert and make one table instead an array of tables?

Comment: I don't understand your question. you're creating nested tables, why do you expect something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to unpack here, so here goes:

1. The table you mention is an associative array of associative arrays.
2. "t0.l1[#t0.l1+1] =" means "figure out which record number we're at in array t0.l1 and add one to it.  Then assign the RHS to that index."

By definition, line #2 is only ever going to assign to a numbered index, which you have stated by example isn't what you want.  To make the associative array of associative arrays you mention in the first example, you can do this one of two general ways (assuming you want it to end up being "t0"):

```
t0 = {
  l1 = {
    t1 = function(params) print('t1') end,
    t2 = function(params) print('t2') end
  },
  l2 = {
    t3 = function(params) print('t3') end
  }
}
```

Or:

```
t0 = {}
t0["l1"] = {}
t0["l1"]["t1"] = function(params) print('t1') end
t0["l1"]["t2"] = function(params) print('t2') end
t0["l2"] = {}
t0["l2"]["t3"] = function(params) print('t3') end
```

(You could also assign interim values like 'tmp = {} ... t0["l2"] = tmp')

Either of these will get you what you want (assuming that it's the associative array of associative arrays mentioned in the first example).

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
t0.l1[#t0.l1+1] = { ['t1'] = function(params) print('t1') end }
```

you are inserting that new table {t1=function() end} in the first index of the t0.l1 table. That happens because #t0.l1 == 0 since until now you had inside t0.l1 two elements defined by their own key (so you were using t0.l1 as a dictionary) and the operator # only works for lists (not dictionaries). So now you have 3 elements, one at index **1** and the others at index **t1** and **t2**.